# What are examples for a "restricted context" in Android?

Tags: android, android-context

The `Context` class has a method `isRestricted`, which, according to the documentation,

> Indicates whether this Context is restricted.

This method returns `false` by default in the `Context` class.

```
public boolean isRestricted() {
    return false;
}
```

I was not able to find any examples for `Context` subclasses that actually have a restricted context.
What are some examples and what effect does this have exactly?

Comment: from commit: *A restricted Context is a special type of Context that prevents specific features
from being used. For instance, android:onClick, used by View, can be dangerous when
used from within apps widgets. By using a restricted Context to inflate apps widgets,
widgets providers are prevented from using android:onClick.*

Answer (score 1):

More information is available in the documentation for the flag `CONTEXT_RESTRICTED` -- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#CONTEXT_RESTRICTED

> Flag for use with `createPackageContext(String, int)`: a restricted context may disable specific features. For instance, a View associated with a restricted context would ignore particular XML attributes.

Seems like, therefore, only a `Context` created via `createPackageContext()` and passed this flag would return `true` from `isRestricted()`.

Comment: Thank you, it certainly helps getting a step closer. I wish I would find some real-life examples for that,